# Ember Data plural serializer

Tags: ember.js

I have a `product` model, and a `/products/` route - however ember data sends a request to `host/api/v1/product` instead of `host/api/v1/products` - why is this?

Also, how can I use the plural end point for individual product fetch? i.e: `host/api/v1/product/1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check **buildURL** method

```
By default, it pluralizes the type's name (for example, 'post'
becomes 'posts' and 'person' becomes 'people'). To override the
pluralization see [pathForType](#method_pathForType).
```

and there is list of sub-methods ( https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.6.1/addon/-private/adapters/build-url-mixin.js#L54 )

```
switch (requestType) {
  case 'findRecord':
    return this.urlForFindRecord(id, modelName, snapshot);
  case 'findAll':
    return this.urlForFindAll(modelName, snapshot);
  case 'query':
    return this.urlForQuery(query, modelName);
  case 'queryRecord':
    return this.urlForQueryRecord(query, modelName);
  case 'findMany':
    return this.urlForFindMany(id, modelName, snapshot);
  case 'findHasMany':
    return this.urlForFindHasMany(id, modelName, snapshot);
  case 'findBelongsTo':
    return this.urlForFindBelongsTo(id, modelName, snapshot);
  case 'createRecord':
    return this.urlForCreateRecord(modelName, snapshot);
  case 'updateRecord':
    return this.urlForUpdateRecord(id, modelName, snapshot);
  case 'deleteRecord':
    return this.urlForDeleteRecord(id, modelName, snapshot);
  default:
    return this._buildURL(modelName, id);
}
```

so you can redefine any for your purposes

Answer (score 0):

Update Your Adapter As Below :

```
import JSONAPIAdapter from 'ember-data/adapters/json-api';

export default JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    pathForType: function(type) {
       var camelized = Ember.String.camelize(type);
       return Ember.String.singularize(camelized);
     }
});
```